# core audio callback, inTimeStamp at the beginning or end of recording

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, core-audio, audiounit

In core audio, when the `recordingCallback` is called:

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {
```

does `inTimeStamp` reference the time when the audio began to be received or the time when the audio was finished being received.

was it

X if X is equal to the time when recording began

or

X + the buffer length

thank you,

nonono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp is for the time when the buffer was captured, specifically the bus time of the system (see this [thread on the CoreAudio mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2008/Oct/msg00272.html) for details). So it would refer to the time in the first sample of the buffer, not the last sample.

Comment: Hi, what would inTimeStamp in the playback callback refer to